# "Kernel died, restarting" in Spyder after installing a package through setup.py

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, spyder

Series of events:

1. Tried to install Pyramid package.
2. I've proxy issues, so I always have to download wheel files and install them manually.
3. Since Pyramid package had dependencies, I had to download and install whl files for those dependencies first.
4. I had trouble installing whl file for this package - `zope.interface` ([link](https://pypi.org/project/zope.interface/#files)) and went ahead with downloading `.gz` file and installing using `setup.py`
5. It broke pip. It wouldn't do anything and say `AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'`
6. Looked online for the same and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52243711/4619760) solution that suggests editing `Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py` file and making some changes
7. Specifically, it suggested changing `orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)` to `orig_path = sorted(orig_path, key=position_in_sys_path)` and it worked. I could install remaining dependencies and install Pyramid as well.
8. But somewhere in the process, Spyder started showing 'Kernel Died, Restarting' in loop.

I've tried a few solutions with no success:

1. Changing `__init__` file back to original. It doesn't fix Spyder and breaks pip anyway.
2. Tried `spyder --reset`
3. Tried `spyder -show-console`. It shows nothing.
4. Unlike [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3899) similar query, I don't have any firewall issues with Anaconda/Spyder since I've been using it for a while now. It broke after today's incident.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I'd say you broke your Anaconda installation by all that mumbo-jumbo and you have to reinstall it again. Next time, please use conda environments to test things like that.